# How to use a recursive type as the return type of a funtion (safe setIn function example)

Tags: typescript

Say I want to create a return type for a function called `setIn`. This function takes an object, key path (i.e `['a', 'b']`) and a value to set to that key path.

eg. `const result = setIn({a: 'test'}, ['a'], 'test2')`

I've created a type that correctly validates that the key path exists

```
type IsValidSet = MySet<{ a: string }, ['a', 'b'], 'test2'>;  
// correctly evals to never as 'b' doesn't exist in { a: string }
```

```
interface AnyObject {
  [key: string]: any;
}

type MySet<
  Obj extends AnyObject,
  Path extends string[],
  Value,
  OriginalObject extends AnyObject = Obj,
> = Path extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? First extends keyof Obj
    ? Rest extends string[]
      ? MySet<Obj[First], Rest, Value, OriginalObject>
      : never
    : never
  : OriginalObject;
```

However when I apply this to a function called `safeSetIn`, the value returned by the function seems to not evaluate to `never`.

```
const safeSetIn = <Obj extends AnyObject, Path extends string[], Value>(
  obj: Obj,
  path: Path,
  value: Value
): MySet<Obj, Path, Value> =>
  unsafeSetIn(path, value, obj) as MySet<Obj, Path, Value>;

const mock: { a: string } = {
  a: 'test',
};

const result = safeSetIn(mock, ['a', 'b'], 'test2'); // result should be of type never but is of type {a: string}
```

Wonder if recursive types don't work as return types?

Thanks!

Comment: • Are you clobbering the native `Set` type on purpose? Could you maybe change the name so as not to confuse people? • You could use IntelliSense to probe what's happening; you can see that `Path` is inferred as `string[]`, since people often don't need tuple types inferred for arrays. You can use a `const` type parameter as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wvon3w) to help inference. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks that fixed it @jcalz and yes I was incorrectly calling the type Set which depending on the file would cause a conflict with the native Set type and was bad practice anyway due to it being confusing. I've edited the question to clear that up.

Comment: If anyone else sees this the playground link fixes that. You can also make the type of obj in the safeSetIn fn be of the type so that if they pass in an object that doesn't contain the path, it will have an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that when you call `safeSetIn(mock, ['a', 'b'], 'test2')`, TypeScript infers `string[]` for the type of the second argument and thus for the `Path` type argument, which throws away the information you need. TypeScript uses heuristics to determine the most appropriate type to infer for a value, and in this case it's not doing what you want.

Luckily there's an easy remedy: you can make `Path` a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to give the compiler a hint that you want it to infer a more specific type, as if you had used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) at the call site, like `['a', 'b'] as const`:

```
const safeSetIn = <
    Obj extends AnyObject,
    const Path extends string[],
    Value
>(obj: Obj, path: Path, value: Value):
    MySet<Obj, Path, Value> =>
    null! as MySet<Obj, Path, Value>;
```

And now things work as you expect:

```
const mock: { a: string } = {
    a: 'test',
};

const result = safeSetIn(mock, ['a', 'b'], 'test2'); // never
/* const safeSetIn: <{a: string;}, ["a", "b"], string>(⋯) => never */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgZwGoEMA2BLAJgZSiGAXhgFkw8QAeAbxhQC4YEQAnDAOwHMYBfAGhgBtAOQphA4QCNhAXQkgozAEzCAfAG5gAei0wAxgHsWLKHpBowMKADd0CGCAMx2NqCzr2pwmFgOL2wgRQAB4YzDAcMLQMTKwc3DzAwBwKLABmKHqwAILsYADykgBWpgTUwDCVQgDWUGCMzGxcMowoeZqJoJCwZBSUFVWFRVbBCuxY9rkFxaV8A5UACiggABYjYxOxTZyCcvMwqGgArlBzVTD5bJwc6EOl61Djk3l3ZkQXxXOq70urD09CDhpNwwABiGBYzAEADpYUCQQAlRQgGT7AD8YIh4RCG3stTABjSHyK6JgSOxo0em0a8V2pN6+EoQ0E4MhKIE5JAAkOJwElww13YtxmZlU+0YLmsbnFzlcLBl-MFwpKZk0SUM7HCCBQwIocHY7365yG-02U1eXP2GvCvzWOKp9hpXF2ZyqPKgwFUAAoDMVGEMBBBlitGLaBLZjlBGO6AJT0fYMqgBmBhg7oE7fQhi87sI5oNAAQg8pHIjOTqfdGnVBk1BAAtgY9NVGNEGnEuLx3uVzjFAsjxMAeGrrQQTAg8wRiNrdfh9V6G02BCIxBJpHIYH3lMIY+oYDpZVL5VoAFT6GtanVQPXsRg0GJOzjqfhCABEKBfAhfkhf64f3sA90QxkQ3ySiCx5aMAQA)